# Swich on external device using COM port

Tags: c#, serial-port

Is it possible to on/off an external relay using serial port's control signals?
I know that is its possible using UART. But here I need to do that without using a micro-controller.

Its better somebody can give a sample code in C#

Thanks.

```
//Here is my code
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";

serialPort1.Open();
serialPort1.DtrEnable = true; //High (On)

Thread.Sleep(1000); //Delay a Second
serialPort1.DtrEnable = false; //Low (Off)
serialPort1.Close();
```

Comment: You will have better luck using a parallel port.

Comment: Somebody negatively voted, may I know why? any errors in question? Yes. Its possible with parallel port. But nowadays most PC's dot have a one! Then is it possible with USB to Parallel converter?

Comment: -1. from me because: 1. you should make research is it possible or not. 2. you should try to send something via serial port and then if you get stuck ask what are you doing wrong.

Comment: a UART is a chip used in COM communications.

Comment: spend some money and buy here does exactly what you want http://www.controlanything.com/

Comment: I have done, I tried this. But nothing happens.   
serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;//High (On) serialPort1.DtrEnable = false;//Low (Off)

Comment: Ok so why cant you add to your question what you already tied? we can help you with your code how to send data to serial port, but what data need to send, well you should know.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm new comer here. I thought there may be different ways for doing this.

Comment: Copy paste code you are trying, well see maybe what you need is just `serialPort1.Open();` line.

Comment: //Here is my code
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
    serialPort1.Open();
    
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;//High (On)
    Thread.Sleep(1000);//Delay a Second
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = false;//Low (Off)
    
    serialPort1.Close();

Comment: have you tried to set DtrEnable = true; before Open()?

Answer (score 1):

You can send info via the serial port using [`System.Io.Ports.Serialport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) but frankly how are we supposed to know what signal is required to turn on your external device?

Comment: I need to use one of control lines (DTR/RTS) to trigger the external circuit. Thats all!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the voltage and current rating needed to turn the relay on/off doesn't exceed the serial ports specifications, it should work, but this is at your own peril.  I would have a driver circuit.

Ask the question at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but I remember, some of the control change state when the port is opened and closed. If you add a transistor to one of those lines it cam provide enough current to turn the relay on/off by opening and closing the port.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Visual Basic 6. I made a form and added the Microsoft comm control (mscomm32.ocx). Basically what I do is put the comm port open and quit it when I quit the form. When the comm port is open there is 5v power to pin 4 (Data Terminal Ready) of the comm port. Together with te ground I connected this to a relay. This has a 5V connection witch is able to switch another power connection up to 250V 5A. So you can turn every device on off if you wish.

The relay I use is an Omron G5NB-1A-E PCB Relay. The 2 pins on 1 small site is 5V. The other on the longer side is for switching external devices

This is my code

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    MSComm1.PortOpen = True 'Not MSComm1.PortOpen

    If Err Then MsgBox Error$, 48

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    MSComm1.PortOpen = 0  '(=False)

    End

End Sub
```

Update: May 25.
I've noticed that  when your PC is booting and you're logging in the relay switches a few times on.
In my case i wanted to reboot another PC with the relay.
I wanted this cross-wise. The other PC must be able to reboot this PC. So i can't have a relay switching on while logging in.
I have to search further. Tha means with data transmission or i.ve found somewhere an USB switcher.
It's here: http://sigma-shop.com/product.php?ProductID=7