# raise individual serial port signals

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Is it possible to raise/lower and read individual serial port lines from a C#/.NET application?

Like:

```
serialPort.Raise(DTR);
serialPort.Drop(CTS);
bool ctrStatus = serialPort.Read(DTR);
```

It doesn't seem to be possible from the `SerialPort` class.

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324603/swich-on-external-device-using-com-port

Comment: By Raise and Lower are do you mean pulling the line high or low?

Comment: Yes [In my question]. It that possible?

Comment: @BarrieK: Yes, that is what I mean. I also need to read the status of some line, i.e. whether it is currently high/low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pins you can control, you do via reading and writing properties.

i.e.

```
if (serialPort.DsrHolding)
```

note that the ability to set pins interacts with hardware handshaking if you have that configured.

For more control than that, you'll need to access the Win32 API directly (for example using p/invoke or C++/CLI).  The [`EscapeCommFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363254.aspx) gives direct control over the control outputs and [`GetCommModemStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363258.aspx) queries the control inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DtrEnable` and `CtsEnable` properties.

Comment: Why are you using parentheses with a property?

Comment: I am not sure if the '..Enable' functions actively set the line to high, _or_ just enable them to be used during communication.

Comment: The Data Terminal Ready signal says to connected peripherals that your computer is ready to recieve/send data (for instance for a modem). The RTS indicates a desire to transmit, and the reciever asserts CTS in response to grant permission. You have full control of these lines.